# Oracle to MySQL migration two questions about syntax differences

Tags: mysql, indexing, constraints, uppercase

Two questions on Mysql:

1) We try to port this code from oracle to mysql:

```
CREATE INDEX "IDX_NAME" ON "TABLE" (UPPER("NAME"))
```

Is this possible with mysql, somewhere I read it isn´t necessary because searches are per default case insensitive, true or not?

2) What is the correlating pattern for NOVALIDATE? How would sth like this look in mysql syntax:

```
CONSTRAINT "FK_DUP" FOREIGN KEY ("DUP") REFERENCES "TABLE" ("ID") ENABLE NOVALIDATE
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: regarding the first question: no, MySQL does not support function based indexes. Although in that case you probably don't need it as MySQL uses case-insensitive character comparison by default.

Answer (score 3):

For your 2nd question, here is what you can do

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE TABLE_NAME 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DUP 
FOREIGN KEY (DUP) 
REFERENCES TABLE_NAME(ID)
```

This will work as ENABLE NOVALIDATE in MySQL.